"Cнег" as a slang term for "cocaine"
Wiktionary says that снег is slang for cocaine, but I can't find any real examples of this. Would you say понюхать снегом for "to snort cocaine", or how would it be said? Thanks.

what exactly you can not find? "снег" and "снежок" are indeed slang words for cocaine, I'm not aware of any specific phrases, but the fact that this two words are used that way (with examples of usage) is easily googleable. Anyway, your phrase is ungrammatical and nobody will is снегом in instrumental.

After some time Googling, I now think it is занюхать снег with за-

I googled and immediately found this example: https://rutube.ru/shorts/34db87b9ef1739a1a37a103c7c617e32 "У мальчика снег закончился"

In Russian slang more typical to use word кокос or кокс for cocaine. Снег or снежок are more typical for movies translation.

how would it be said?

Here are couple of slang expressions:
* Понюхать/дунуть кокса
* Нюхнуть кокса
* Дунуть кокос

